Unable to animate transition inside a WindowGroup
I am trying to animate a conditional view render using a transition. I prepared this minimal example:
@State private var showOnboarding: Bool = false

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        VStack {
            if showOnboarding {
                Text("Onboarding")
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                Text("Main View")
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
            
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    showOnboarding.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

This does not work. When I move the body contents (VStack) into a ContentView:
@State private var showOnboarding: Bool = false

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {

@State private var showOnboarding: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if showOnboarding {
            Text("Onboarding")
                .transition(.slide)
        } else {
            Text("Main View")
                .transition(.slide)
        }
        
        Button("Toggle") {
            withAnimation {
                showOnboarding.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

Then it magically starts working. I haven't found a mention of this in the official docs. Any reason for this? Why does not wrapping the changing content inside a container like VStack or Group help and only moving to a separate view file helps?
